# How does quantum theory allow a rock to turn suddenly into a duck?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, randomness

Quantum theory does not allow a rock to turn suddenly into a duck. It does not allow any other bizarre transformation to happen either. This idea is a myth perpetuated by people who misunderstand quantum theory. Foundational to quantum theory is the concept of particle uncertainty. It is impossible to know a particle's exact location and exact momentum at the same time. Furthermore, a quantum particle's exact location and exact momentum does not even exist at the same time. The uncertainty in quantum theory is not a result of measurement limitations but is inherent to each quantum object itself. The more you try to trap a single electron and therefore force it to have a more defined position, the less defined becomes its momentum. This uncertainty means that quantum particles can end up in unexpected places. The more unexpected its destination, the less likely it is to end up there, but the probability is never zero. So, does quantum theory allow a rock to turn suddenly into a duck? (Source: wtamu.edu)

Comment: I am puzzled that this question has a majority of downvotes, with upvoted answers. Could the people who downvoted perhaps provide a reason for doing so? As the currently highest voted answer (correctly) points out, in standard QM there is some non-zero (but tiny) probability for such type of processes to occur, provided the relevant conservation laws are not violated. This is the content of Gell-Mann’s totalitarian principle: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarian_principle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does quantum theory allow a rock to turn suddenly into a duck?

Yes in theory, No in practice.

In an abstract sense there's nothing preventing the rock from being reconfigured into a duck.  It's just a rearrangement of energies and a redistribution of conserved quantities.

In practice the **probability** of this happening is too small to be worth considering, even in the entire lifetime of the universe.

It would require a very convenient (from the duck's point of view) rearrangement of a huge number of particles into a completely different one - including some nuclear transformations that would be pretty energetic in terms of released energy that cannot be kept.  Probably the process would be more like a nuclear weapon going off than a duck magically appearing.

So you'd very briefly get a vaporized duck, I suspect.

A duck is about 1 kilo and a kilo of rock is at least required.  That kilo contains something on the order of $10^{24}$ atoms and you want to completely rearrange them which would require a number of operations of something on the order of (guess) $(10^{24}) !$ events to happen at the same time (that's factorial $10^{24}$ which would be too large a number to write down).  The probability of that happening is so tiny as to be essentially zero.

Comment: Using Stirling's approximation, the number of digits in $10^{k}!$ is about $1/2\log_{10}(2\pi)+k/2+(k-1)10^{k}$. For $k=24$, you need $\approx 23*10^{24}$ digits to write this number down. You could do it with a 30 yottabyte hard drive.

Comment: If it looks like a rock, and it walks like a rock, and it "quacks" like a rock, it's a rock.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I suppose the particles that make up a rock could spontaneously re-arrange themselves into a duck, but the probability of that happening is vanishingly small. And there are conservation laws that have to be obeyed in quantum physics - for example, energy still has to be conserved, within the bounds set by Heisenberg's uncertainty principle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems implausible. Start with a nice big chunk of quartz. Silicon dioxide. A duck is largely made of water. We already have more than enough oxygen, but it would be necessary to convert some of the silicon into hydrogen. That takes a lot of energy. More silicon or oxygen would have to change to carbon, and nitrogen. Lots of energy needed, and we don't right off know any mechanism for it.

However, there is a whole lot of physics that nobody understands yet. So it might not be as unlikely as it at first seems.

I believe the most plausible way for it to happen is for humans to eventually learn enough physics to create something like a Star Trek matter converter.

And then possibly they might find it convenient to store raw materials in the form of silicon dioxide. Also that might be the stuff on the earth's crust they find most generally useless. So they build a bunch of matter converters, and one day somebody wants a nice dinner and they punch in a preference for roast duck, and it happens.

That may not be possible at all, but if it IS possible then it looks far more likely than any other way.